# Put data from Hive tables to kafka topic via nifi

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have few tables in Hive and my goal is to create a view over them and then  publish it over a topic in Kafka through Apache NiFi.

What are the options to get it done?

I am planning to do it through Nifi .

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Nifi would work,
see `PutHiveStreaming` processor, but sounds like a lot of effort.

[Kafka Connect HDFS](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) is able to consume Kafka data and automatically register a Hive table for you.

---

And if I misunderstood that, and you're trying to query Hive and publish it into a Kafka topic, then sure - Nifi is perfectly capable of that

Use `SelectHiveQL` and `PublishKafka`, however Kafka Connect JDBC Source should be able to query Hive and write to Kafka as well

Comment: I know Nifi will do the trick for you can you please point me in the rights processors direction as i have difficulty in finding the right ones in this case.

Comment: Put or Consume Kakfa? ExecuteSQL? At least filtering on Kafka or SQL will get you reasonable results